# Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed | due error in cpp file

Tags: c++, ros, catkin

This error comes when I run catkin_make command in catkin_ws directory. I think there are problems in off_node.ccp file as first error appears which is related to cpp file and leads to further error messages, which I am not able to debug. I added off_node.ccp programme below error message.

```
Base path: /home/yograj/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/install
Error(s) in /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src/px4_mavros/package.xml:
- The manifest (with format version 2) must not contain the following tags: run_depend
yograj@yograj-Inspiron-5537:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/yograj/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/install
Error(s) in /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src/px4_mavros/package.xml:
- The manifest (with format version 2) must not contain the following tags: run_depend
yograj@yograj-Inspiron-5537:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/yograj/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- This workspace overlays: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/kinetic
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using empy: /usr/bin/empy
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- Using Python nosetests: /usr/bin/nosetests-2.7
-- catkin 0.7.8
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - px4_mavros
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'px4_mavros'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(px4_mavros)
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/yograj/catkin_ws/build
####
#### Running command: "make -j4 -l4" in "/home/yograj/catkin_ws/build"
####
[ 50%] Building CXX object px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/src/offb_node.cpp.o
/home/yograj/catkin_ws/src/px4_mavros/src/offb_node.cpp: In function ‘int main(int, char**)’:
/home/yograj/catkin_ws/src/px4_mavros/src/offb_node.cpp:53:40: error: ‘mavros_msgs::SetMode::Response {aka struct mavros_msgs::SetModeResponse_<std::allocator<void> >}’ has no member named ‘success’
                 offb_set_mode.response.success){
                                        ^
px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/src/offb_node.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/src/offb_node.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:823: recipe for target 'px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [px4_mavros/CMakeFiles/offb_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

Here is programme of off_node.cpp file

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <geometry_msgs/PoseStamped.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/CommandBool.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/SetMode.h>
#include <mavros_msgs/State.h>
mavros_msgs::State current_state;
void state_cb(const mavros_msgs::State::ConstPtr& msg){
    current_state = *msg;
}
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "offb_node");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Subscriber state_sub = nh.subscribe<mavros_msgs::State>
            ("mavros/state", 10, state_cb);
    ros::Publisher local_pos_pub = nh.advertise<geometry_msgs::PoseStamped>
            ("mavros/setpoint_position/local", 10);
    ros::ServiceClient arming_client = nh.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::CommandBool>
            ("mavros/cmd/arming");
    ros::ServiceClient set_mode_client = nh.serviceClient<mavros_msgs::SetMode>
            ("mavros/set_mode");
    //the setpoint publishing rate MUST be faster than 2Hz
    ros::Rate rate(20.0);
    // wait for FCU connection
    while(ros::ok() && current_state.connected){
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    geometry_msgs::PoseStamped pose;
    pose.pose.position.x = 0;
    pose.pose.position.y = 0;
    pose.pose.position.z = 2;
    //send a few setpoints before starting
    for(int i = 100; ros::ok() && i > 0; --i){
        local_pos_pub.publish(pose);
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    mavros_msgs::SetMode offb_set_mode;
    offb_set_mode.request.custom_mode = "OFFBOARD";
    mavros_msgs::CommandBool arm_cmd;
    arm_cmd.request.value = true;
    ros::Time last_request = ros::Time::now();
    while(ros::ok()){
        if( current_state.mode != "OFFBOARD" &&
            (ros::Time::now() - last_request > ros::Duration(5.0))){
            if( set_mode_client.call(offb_set_mode) &&
                offb_set_mode.response.success){
                ROS_INFO("Offboard enabled");
            }
            last_request = ros::Time::now();
        } else {
            if( !current_state.armed &&
                (ros::Time::now() - last_request > ros::Duration(5.0))){
                if( arming_client.call(arm_cmd) &&
                    arm_cmd.response.success){
                    ROS_INFO("Vehicle armed");
                }
                last_request = ros::Time::now();
            }
        }
        local_pos_pub.publish(pose);
        ros::spinOnce();
        rate.sleep();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are Looking At Wrong Documentation probably
cause in [kinetic doc](http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/mavros_msgs/html/srv/SetMode.html):

`mavros_msgs::SetMode` has no success in response instead there's `mode_sent`